# Python List Comprehension aggregating tuple data

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I've got a list with tuples that looks like this. Each tuple is a baseball player, and then stats for that player. **Note that multiple tuples in the list (the actual list is much bigger than this) may contain the same player but with stats from a different baseball game.

```
[('Jimmy Brown', '4', '0', '0'), ('Jimmy Brown', '4', '1', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '5', '0', '0'), ('Enos Slaughter', '3', '2', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '3', '1', '1')]
```

I want to do calculations for each player. In the example list above, I might want to calculate the average of the 3rd index for Jimmy Brown. So I'd want (0+1)/2. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: tuples, not truples.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Don't know why, but I kinda detect an assignment due before tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

> In the example list above, I might want to calculate the average of
>   the 3rd index for Jimmy Brown.

Note that you'll have to filter your list for only the tuples containing Jimmy Brown.

```
l = [('Jimmy Brown', '4', '0', '0'), ('Jimmy Brown', '4', '1', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '5', '0', '0'), ('Enos Slaughter', '3', '2', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '3', '1', '1')]
cumulative = 0
num =0
for t in l:
    if t[0]=='Jimmy Brown':
        cumulative += t[3]
        num +=1
return cumulative/float(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the inner tuples based on the first element on the tuple, and then for each inner group take the required average. Example -

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
for i,grp in groupby(sorted(lst),key=itemgetter(0)):
    grplst = list(grp)
    print(i," - ", sum(float(x) for _,_,x,_ in grplst)/len(grplst))
```

Demo -

```
>>> lst = [('Jimmy Brown', '4', '0', '0'), ('Jimmy Brown', '4', '1', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '5', '0', '0'), ('Enos Slaughter', '3', '2', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '3', '1', '1')]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> for i,grp in groupby(sorted(lst),key=itemgetter(0)):
...     grplst = list(grp)
...     print(i," - ", sum(float(x) for _,_,x,_ in grplst)/len(grplst))
...
Enos Slaughter  -  2.0
Jimmy Brown  -  0.5
Stu Martin  -  0.5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
l = [('Jimmy Brown', '4', '0', '0'), ('Jimmy Brown', '4', '1', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '5', '0', '0'), ('Enos Slaughter', '3', '2', '1'), ('Stu Martin', '3', '1', '1')]

l_jimmy = [ float( item[ 2 ] ) for item in l if item[ 0 ] == 'Jimmy Brown' ]

# or via map/filter:
l_jimmy = map( lambda x: float( x[ 2 ] ), filter( lambda x: x[ 0 ] == 'Jimmy Brown', l ) )

# final calculation
avg = sum( l_jimmy ) / len( l_jimmy )
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it has been fixed.